# Printer connectivity

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I am trying to connect my printer - an Epson stylus SX445W.

This printer has WiFi and usb connectivity. Via the system settings, not a single printer appears nor does Ubuntu respond to the search option. I would have thought that it would be plug&play.

Answer (score 0):

Epson's website has a link to another Epson website containing DEBs of all the drivers needed. Just look up the printer and install the driver, and then add the printer in Printer settings. For any questions on installing the DEBs post in comments.

Here is the link to the [drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult). You may still need to look up the term: SX445W to find them.

Specific DEB links:

Print Driver:  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=45429&DSCCHK=eaf97ae6689ee7a594faa68cb24949fb6569b055

Print Driver:  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16876&DSCCHK=b32e8a0bd44cc61369c3fa75fbab6b877ce71d25

Print Driver:  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=45427&DSCCHK=dbd222ef019e11433beed9d553bd567029c06dd8

Scanner Driver:  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=44399&DSCCHK=92728c39b03068c053bae544323f8b97929fbfce

Those are just the pages, scroll to the bottom of the page for instructions and downloads.